# Listen for MsTest Events in Visual Studio Addin

Tags: mstest, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-addins

Any way to catch test events inside a Visual Studio Addin? I dont see anything inside DTE2 that will do the trick. I would like to know when a test run is started and when it is completed. And then get the test results.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT
If I could know when MsTest tests are run that would be sufficient and it would be preferable to have something that would not be VS version specific. I would rather not have to write version specific code for each VS Version or have to write a different add in for each version.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken a look, and it seems to me that the testing framework and DTE are kind of separate between each other, didn't exactly seem like the testing framework exposed anything to the DTE/VisualStudio.

The closest thing I found was [Creating a Diagnostic Data Adapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286649.aspx). To me it seems like you could possibly use this to intercept all the events & dispatch them through some kind of communication to your VS addin.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I looked into it and it seems that custom diagnostic data adapters can only be configured for use in Visual Studio Ultimate, Premium, or Test Professional and would also required some configuration of test settings. It could work, but I dont have the right version of VS to try and not everyone who will use my plugin have the correct versions. I will keep looking. If I find something I will update this post. Thanks again.

Comment: @andrewramka, you'll need to know that the architecture of tests have been changing constantly. You should update the question, and explain a bit more what you're looking. What visual Studio version? Are you looking it to work with any testing framework, or just only MsTest? As 2013 can run different test "frameworks", such as nUnit..